# Calling a Fortran function that returns an array of a derived type from C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, makefile, fortran

I have a fortran derived type

```
type, bind(c):: waveform

 real(c_double)::x 
 real(c_double)::y 

 real(c_double)::lat

 real(c_double)::windspeed !Wind speed at that point                                                                                       
 real(c_double)::a !Willougby A parameter                                                                                                  

 real(c_double)::startX
 real(c_double)::startY

 real(c_double)::data(600)
```

end type waveform

I wrote a function that returns an array of the waveform type

```
  function getWilloughby()

    type(waveform), allocatable, dimension(:)::getWilloughby
```

I want to call the Fortran function from a C++ program so I made a struct corresponding to the derived type and a prototype function.

```
  waveform *getWilloughby_();
```

I'm a bit stuck because to my understanding C++ doesn't return arrays by value and I'm not sure if my Makefile is correct.

When I compile I get the following error.

```
undefined reference to `getWilloughby_()'
```

Here's my Makefile

```
 ORIG_INC_PATH = -I/usr/include
 ORIG_LAB_PATH = -L/usr/lib

 CUDA_INC_PATH = -I/usr/local/cuda-6.0/targets/x86_64-linux/include
 CUDA_LIB_PATH = -L/usr/local/cuda-6.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib


 full:
    g++ -c cross_correlation.cpp -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lcublas -lcufft -lafcuda -o cross_correlation.o -g $(CUDA_INC_PATH) $(CUDA_LIB_PATH)

    gfortran -c load_files.f90

    g++ -o matched_filter load_files.o cross_correlation.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -lgfortran -lcudart-lcublas -lcufft -lafcuda $(CUDA_INC_PATH) $(CUDA_LIB_PATH)
```

Am I declaring the function wrong in C++? Have I written my Makefile incorrectly? Or is there something else at play?

Comment: Why don't you make the function `bind(C)` too, when you are already using the Fortran-C interop? Do you use `extern(C)` in the C+ code?

Comment: Ok I'll add the bind(C). No I don't have extern(C). What does that do?

Comment: `extern "C"` is similar to `bind(C)`, but is used in C++ to specify the function has C linkage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c  If it doesn't halp you will have to show more of your C++ code.

Comment: Also, your Fortran header looks suspicious, you should show the complete form. Namely, do not try to use allocatable function results and pass it to C as a pointer!

Comment: when I add the bind(c) to the function it says "Variable 'getwilloughby' at (1) cannot have both the ALLOCATABLE and BIND(C) attributes"

Comment: what's the proper way to return it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70432/discussion-between-eddie-e-massey-iii-and-vladimir-f).

Comment: See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351919/passing-allocated-c-ptr-to-fortran-array-to-c